Traversal Heap Sort (No Extractions)
I developed a heap sort variant that sorts a heap through traversal. Unlike in the standard heap sort, the algorithm does not remove the min element from the heap instead it traverses all the nodes of the heap visiting those with smaller values first and adding them to the sorted list
Here’s the implementation of the algorithm in python:
import heapq

def heap_sort(lst):
  """
  Performs a heap sort iteratively by traversing all nodes of the heap, visiting nodes with smaller values first and adding the values to sorted result list.

  Args:
    lst (list): The input list to be sorted.
  Returns:
    list: A sorted list containing elements of the input list in ascending order.

  Approach:
  - Convert the input list into a min-heap
  - Traverse and process the heap iteratively:
    - Maintain a set to track indices that have already been processed.
    - Replace the value at the current node with the value of either the left child, right child or parent, depending on specific conditions.
  - Accumulate results in a separate list as each node is processed.
  """

  def left_child(i):
    """
    Returns the value of the left child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
    """
    return float("inf") if 2 * i + 1 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 1]

  def right_child(i):
    """
    Returns the value of the right child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
    """
    return float("inf") if 2 * i + 2 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 2]

  def parent(i):
    """
    Returns the value of parent of the node at index i, or infinity if the node is the root.
    """
    return lst[(i - 1) // 2] if i > 0 else float("inf")

  heapq.heapify(lst)  # Build a min-heap from input list

  # A set to keep track of visited indices (nodes)
  visited_indices = set()

  # List to store the sorted result
  result = []

  # Start traversal from the root of the heap
  current_index = 0  

  while len(result) < len(lst):
    if current_index not in visited_indices:
      # Add the current node's value to the result and mark it as visited
      result.append(lst[current_index])
      visited_indices.add(current_index)
    # Replace the current node value with value of either left, right or parent node
    if parent(current_index) < min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index)):
      lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index))
      current_index = (current_index - 1) // 2  # Move to the parent node
    elif left_child(current_index) < right_child(current_index):
      lst[current_index] = min(right_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
      current_index = 2 * current_index + 1  # Move to the left child
    else:
      lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
      current_index = 2 * current_index + 2  # Move to the right child

  return result

The algorithm's main steps are:

Convert the input list into a min-heap using heapq.heapify.

Initialize result to an empty list [ ]

Traverse the heap iteratively starting with root node and replace the current node's value with either the value of parent, left child or right child based on specific conditions. The traversal logic ensures that the parent node "calls" the smaller of it's children to explore its subtree until a node with value greater than the parent is encountered. If the children of the current node are all greater than the value of the parent of current node, it means the parent node has nodes in its other subtree that have smaller values. In this case, control is returned to parent node

Append the node’s value to the result when it is first visited.


My Questions

How does the algorithm compare to the standard heap sort in terms of efficiency?
Can it be optimized?
Could the iterative traversal logic be simplified while maintaining correctness?

For those interested in a recursive solution, here's the implementation:
import heapq

def heap_sort_re(lst):

  def left_child(i):
    return float("inf") if 2 * i + 1 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 1]

  def right_child(i):
    return float("inf") if 2 * i + 2 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 2]

  def parent(i):
    return lst[(i - 1) // 2] if i > 0 else float("inf")

  def _recurse(i = 0):
    if len(result) == len(lst):
      return
    if i not in visited:
      result.append(lst[i])
      visited.add(i)
    if parent(i) < min(left_child(i), right_child(i)):
      lst[i] = min(left_child(i), right_child(i))
      _recurse((i - 1) // 2)
    elif left_child(i) < right_child(i):
      lst[i] = min(right_child(i), parent(i))
      _recurse( 2*i + 1)
    else:
      lst[i] = min(left_child(i), parent(i))
      _recurse(2*i + 2)

  heapq.heapify(lst)
  visited = set()
  result = []

  _recurse()

  return result


If this offers some advantage over sorted(lst), I am not yet seeing it. Maybe you wanted to add a "reinventing the wheel" tag, to show that this is strictly a learning exercise, not destined for production code?

Did you try and answer your 1. yourself?

@greybeard, the space complexity of the algorithm is obviously O(n) as we need to keep track of visited nodes/indices and also its not in place so another O(n) space for result

As for the time complexity, I haven't done a formal analysis of the algorithm but I believe it runs in nlogn. I did count the number of iterations the while loop makes for various input list sizes n up to 10^6, the iteration counts were between nlogn and 2nlogn strongly suggesting nlogn time complexity

Agreed for space. For time, I suggest comparing to nsmallest(len(lst), lst).

Assuming the heap is already built from a list of size n, nsmallest gets the smallest k elements by repeadly extracting the smallest from the heap resulting in O(k log n) time. For the described algorithm in question, it appears it extracts the smallest k elements from the heap in O(k log k) time (from iteration counts)

To get k smallest elements, just replace the while loop condition len(result) < len(lst) with len(result) < k

"it appears [a trivial modification] extracts the smallest k elements from the heap in O(k log k) time (from iteration counts)" retrofit raison d'être! If you can argue that convincingly, that would be a valuable addition to docstring and interface (ksmalles(iterable, k=None) with None to be substituted by len(lst)).

Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. What to do after the question has been answered.

@pacmaninbw, I had initially named the function heap_sort_custom but later changed to heap_sort. I noticed the answers were using heap_sort_custom so my last edit was to revert the name of the fucntion back to heap_sort_custom

conventional names
  current_index = 0

This name is not great.
Prefer j (so we don't confuse it with the various i parameters).
The OP name appears everywhere, so it is tediously distracting
to pronounce those four syllables.
composition
  heapq.heapify(lst)  # Build a min-heap from input list

This is an expensive operation, and could easily
be invoked by the caller.
Consider making "heapify" the caller's responsibility.
Possibly one could make multiple calls to heap_sort()
or a similar routine, which exploit a pre-ordered list
without need of the heapify overhead.
motivation
It does not appear the proposed heap_sort(lst) offers any
advantage over sorted(lst).
Traditionally the review questions we ask about code at Pull Request time are:

Is it correct?
Is it maintainable?

I'm willing to believe the code is correct, despite the lack of automated
unit tests.
But it absolutely fails the "maintainability" test,
given that every single team member on a project will
already be quite familiar with sorted(lst),
and its performance, and will be confident in its correctness.
Even if timsort was implemented as python bytecode,
I still wouldn't pit some newly minted untuned code against it.
And cPython's timsort is native C code.
I haven't run the OP code, but I am confident timsort is quicker than it is.
If a team member advocated merging such a pull request,
I would not approve it until we saw some motivation,
some feature offered by the code which the builtin sort does not supply.
nsmallest
Given a heapified list, I would expect idiomatic python source
to simply execute
from heapq import nsmallest

    ...
    return nsmallest(len(lst), lst)  # same as `sorted(lst)`

black
The python community does not use an indent level of 2,
because indent has greater importance to python source code
than it does to various children of Algol such as C and JS.
A too-small indent level makes the source less readable to humans.
Run $ black *.py before submitting a PR, so indent details
won't be a distraction.
caller surprise
It's considered a bit rude to trash the caller's input without
mentioning that in the docstring, e.g. lst.sort() or shuffle(lst).
Either make a .copy(), or describe the side effect in the docstring.
strictly increasing
There are several < comparisons where it is not completely
clear we prefer that over <=.
Citing a reference or giving a more complete specification
would help reviewers to resolve such ambiguities.
invariants
The main while loop tries to preserve several invariants,
but it's not completely obvious what they all are.
At least one of them is that "lst shall always be monotonic".
And we have a nice loop variant, that "either result length increases
to lst length, or something something" which is related to \$\log n\$
traversals. But it wasn't immediately obvious to me what the
something something details would be, and that makes the
"this is correct!" argument a bit harder.
Each of the three branches assigns a new value to j (to current_index).
But it's not obvious what promise that assignment makes.
It's worth a # comment,
or better, an assert.
Documenting the lst ordering caller shall see after the call
would be a good start.

@user555045 offers a nice plot of several sort timings.
I add a few more, with minor refactor.
The \$- 1\$ term is to defeat an .nsmallest() optimization,
which would otherwise special case to just use sorted(),
explaining the suspicious resemblance between those two curves
before introducing the \$- 1\$ tweak.
We see that sorted() dominates,
and sort_using_heap() is a strong competitor.
...

def nsmallest(arr):
    heapq.heapify(arr)
    return heapq.nsmallest(len(arr) - 1, arr)  # tweak to deoptimize


def sample(n, fn):
    data = makedata(n)
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: fn(data[:]), number=10)


def plot(ax, a, fn, color):
    ax.plot([sample(n, fn) for n in a], color=color, label=fn.__name__)


def main() -> None:
    a = [pow(2, i) for i in range(1, 19)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

    for color, fn in [
        ("blue", heap_sort_custom),
        ("red", heapsort),
        ("green", sort_using_heap),
        ("purple", nsmallest),
        ("orange", sorted),
    ]:
        plot(ax, a, fn, color)

    ax.set_yscale("log")
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()



I agree it definitely doesn't make sense to prefer untested code like this to using the built in sorted function that's well tested for correctness and optimized for performance. My motivation for posting here is first it's a new approach, I haven't seen any algorithm that simply traverses a heap to obtain a sorted list. And two given the community here, it's possible a good usecase can be found .

(Those graphs differ somewhat from the ones I got (/get after trying "deoptimisation"). They agree on heap_sort_custom & heapsort, but (deoptimised)nsmallest and sorted almost coincide here(3.12). I let it run up to 8M entries; past L3 size heapsort & sort_using_heap converge. The gap between heap_sort_custom and sorted seems to shrink from about 130:1 to 100:1.)


How does the algorithm compare to the standard heap sort in terms of efficiency?

I ran some tests, plotted below. Y is time in seconds, X is the size of the array:

Note the log-log axes, heap_sort_custom is usually ~100x as slow as sort_using_heap, except for tiny arrays.
Full code below. This is not a rewrite, just a test, there are no modifications to heap_sort_custom. heapsort is just some arbitrary implementation of heapsort, the details don't matter. sort_using_heap uses a heap to sort, but isn't heapsort. It's a lot better than I expected, or heapsort is a lot worse, either way I didn't expect a large margin between them but there is - but whatever, both of them are only on the graph to provide some point of reference.
import heapq
import random
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def heap_sort_custom(lst):
    """
    Performs a custom heap sort iterative algorithm without changing the size of the heap. Unlike in standard heap sort, no extractions are performed

    Args:
        lst (list): The input list to be sorted.
    Returns:
        list: A sorted list containing elements of the input list in ascending order.

    Approach:
    - Convert the input list into a min-heap
    - Traverse and process the heap iteratively:
        - Maintain a set to track indices that have already been processed.
        - Replace the value at the current node with the value of either the left child, right child or parent, depending on specific conditions.
    - Accumulate results in a separate list as each node is processed.
    """

    def left_child(i):
        """
        Returns the value of the left child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
        """
        return float("inf") if 2 * i + 1 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 1]

    def right_child(i):
        """
        Returns the value of the right child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
        """
        return float("inf") if 2 * i + 2 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 2]

    def parent(i):
        """
        Returns the value of parent of the node at index i, or infinity if the node is the root.
        """
        return lst[(i - 1) // 2] if i > 0 else float("inf")

    heapq.heapify(lst)  #Build a min-heap from input list

    # A set to keep track of visited indices
    visited_indices = set()

    # List to store the sorted result
    sorted_result = []

    # Start traversal from the root of the heap
    current_index = 0  

    while len(sorted_result) < len(lst):
        if current_index not in visited_indices:
            # Add the current node's value to the result and mark it as visited
            sorted_result.append(lst[current_index])
            visited_indices.add(current_index)
        # Replace the current node value with value of either left, right or parent node
        if parent(current_index) < min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index)):
            lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index))
            current_index = (current_index - 1) // 2  # Move to the parent node
        elif left_child(current_index) < right_child(current_index):
            lst[current_index] = min(right_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
            current_index = 2 * current_index + 1  # Move to the left child
        else:
            lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
            current_index = 2 * current_index + 2  # Move to the right child

    return sorted_result

def sort_using_heap(arr):
    heapq.heapify(arr)
    result = []
    while arr:
        result.append(heapq.heappop(arr))
    return result

def heapsort(arr):
    def sift_down(arr, n, i):
        elem = arr[i]
        while True:
            l = 2 * i + 1
            if l >= n:
                arr[i] = elem
                return
            r = 2 * i + 2
            c = l
            if r < n and arr[l] < arr[r]:
                c = r
            if elem >= arr[c]:
                arr[i] = elem
                return
            arr[i] = arr[c]
            i = c
        
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n // 2, -1, -1):
        sift_down(arr, n, i)
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        t = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[0]
        arr[0] = t
        sift_down(arr, i, 0)
    return arr

def makedata(n):
    res = list(range(n))
    random.seed(a=n)
    random.shuffle(res)
    return res

def sample1(n):
    data = makedata(n)
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: heap_sort_custom(data[:]), number=10)
def sample2(n):
    data = makedata(n)
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: heapsort(data[:]), number=10)
def sample3(n):
    data = makedata(n)
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: sort_using_heap(data[:]), number=10)

a = [pow(2, i) for i in range(1,17)]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.plot(a, [sample1(n)/10 for n in a], color='blue', label='heap_sort_custom')
ax.plot(a, [sample2(n)/10 for n in a], color='red', label='heapsort')
ax.plot(a, [sample3(n)/10 for n in a], color='green', label='sort_using_heap')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


You picked up some advice. I tried heapq.heapify()&nlargest(). And sorted() with a not entirely expected result.

heap_sort(['a', 'short', 'test']) fails, the domain of the function is one more thing I'd prefer the docstring to state.
Following the Style Guide for Python Code more closely has the overall advantage of meeting the expectations of Python coders.
One advantage at SE would be to see most of docstrings, statements and comments without horizontal scrolling.

I believe the reason for the the slowness of heap_sort_custom is mostly in the number of iterations it takes to visit all nodes.
Below is a plot of array size vs iteration count for heap_sort_custom and heapsort.
As seen in the plot, heap_sort_custom makes at least twice as many iterations as heapsort. The key to optimizing heap_sort_custom is in optimizing heap traversal.

I have modified heap_sort_custom and heapsort to count and return the total number of iterations to sort heap. Note that in heapsort, the iteration count does not include those during heap build.
import heapq
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
def heap_sort_custom(lst):
    """
    Performs a custom heap sort iterative algorithm without changing the size of the heap. Unlike in standard heap sort, no extractions are performed

    Args:
        lst (list): The input list to be sorted.
    Returns:
        list: A sorted list containing elements of the input list in ascending order.

    Approach:
    - Convert the input list into a min-heap
    - Traverse and process the heap iteratively:
        - Maintain a set to track indices that have already been processed.
        - Replace the value at the current node with the value of either the left child, right child or parent, depending on specific conditions.
    - Accumulate results in a separate list as each node is processed.
    """
  
    def left_child(i):
        """
        Returns the value of the left child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
        """
        return float("inf") if 2 * i + 1 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 1]

    def right_child(i):
        """
        Returns the value of the right child of the node at index i, or infinity if out of bounds.
        """
        return float("inf") if 2 * i + 2 >= len(lst) else lst[2 * i + 2]

    def parent(i):
        """
        Returns the value of parent of the node at index i, or infinity if the node is the root.
        """
        return lst[(i - 1) // 2] if i > 0 else float("inf")

    heapq.heapify(lst)  # Build a min-heap from input list

    # A set to keep track of visited indices
    visited_indices = set()

    # List to store the sorted result
    sorted_result = []

    # Start traversal from the root of the heap
    current_index = 0

    #total number of while loop iterations  
    iteration_count = 0

    while len(sorted_result) < len(lst):
        iteration_count += 1
        if not current_index in  visited_indices:
            # Add the current node's value to the result and mark it as visited
            sorted_result.append(lst[current_index])
            visited_indices.add(current_index)
        # Replace the current node value with value of either left, right or parent node
        if parent(current_index) < min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index)):
            lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), right_child(current_index))
            current_index = (current_index - 1) // 2  # Move to the parent node
        elif left_child(current_index) < right_child(current_index):
            lst[current_index] = min(right_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
            current_index = 2 * current_index + 1  # Move to the left child
        else:
            lst[current_index] = min(left_child(current_index), parent(current_index))
            current_index = 2 * current_index + 2  # Move to the right child

    return iteration_count
    

def heapsort(arr):
    def sift_down(arr, n, i, build = True):
        elem = arr[i]
        nonlocal iteration_count
        while True:
            if not build:
              iteration_count += 1
            l = 2 * i + 1
            if l >= n:
                arr[i] = elem
                return
            r = 2 * i + 2
            c = l
            if r < n and arr[l] < arr[r]:
                c = r
            if elem >= arr[c]:
                arr[i] = elem
                return
            arr[i] = arr[c]
            i = c

    # total number of sift_down while loop iterations during sorting phase
    # doesn't include iterations during heap build
    iteration_count = 0 

    n = len(arr)
  
    for i in range(n // 2, -1, -1):
        sift_down(arr, n, i)
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        t = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[0]
        arr[0] = t
        sift_down(arr, i, 0, build = False)
    return iteration_count

def makedata(n):
    res = list(range(n))
    random.seed(a=n)
    random.shuffle(res)
    return res

def sample1(n):
    data = makedata(n)
    return heap_sort_custom(data[:])
def sample2(n):
    data = makedata(n)
    return heapsort(data[:])

a = [pow(2, i) for i in range(1,18)]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(a, [sample1(n) for n in a], color='blue', label='heap_sort_custom')
ax.plot(a, [sample2(n) for n in a], color='red', label='heapsort')
ax.set_xlabel('Array Size')
ax.set_ylabel('Iteration Count') 
ax.set_title('Comparison of Iteration Counts')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

